# Finding Services of peripheral

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working with a Laird BT900 Bluetooth dongle which I can program to be a peripheral. When I add a service to it I can find it with a Bluetooth explorer on windows but on android I can find them.

Anyone knows what the problem can be? I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tool are you using on android? I generally use Nordic Semiconductor's NRFconnect tool for android to debug these kinds of issues, as it can provide raw Hex dumps for these kinds issues.

Also check, that you are configuring the service properly, as some modules need to be reset before service changes take place.

If you are writing your own app for android, the NRFconnect tool still comes in handy, as it can help debug something that is wrong in your service discovery code.

Comment: apparently restarting things helped because it works now. But thank for the tip with NRFconnect its a really handy tool